# Pass slug field to url

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to create a detailed view of my model: Product.

But, I'm not getting how to pass the slug-field into the url.

This is my detailed view:

```
def single_product(request):
    product = get_object_or_404(prods, slug=slug)
    return render_to_response('teste.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    #inserir slugify na url do produto
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbs/')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

And this is the value of slug for product 1:'kinect-xbox-360'
But when I try to run: [localhost]/kinect-xbox-360/
I get this message:

```
TypeError at /kinect-xbox-360/
'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the slug to the appropriate url in your `urls.py`. That will then be passed as a parameter in your view:

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^product/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'views.single_product', name='detail'),
...
```

[read more about the url dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/)

**views.py**

```
def single_product(request, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(prods, slug=slug)
    return render_to_response('test.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

[read more about writing function-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#mapping-urls-to-views)

Comment: I tried with url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'single_product', name='detail'), like you said, but I still get 'TypeError at /kinect-xbox-360/'